# AddPostPlugin workaround

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to replicate the workflow posted here: http://renaun.com/blog/2013/09/live-three-js-texture-updating-with-photoshop-cc/

This is a method for automatically refreshing a texture in Three.JS, and uses the code:

```
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.addPostPlugin(new RENAUN.LiveTextureUpdatePlugin());
```

When running with the most recent version of ThreeJS, the error:

> > THREE.WebGLRenderer: .addPostPlugin() has been removed.

Any ideas for a workaround? I can't seem to find much on addPostPlugin and would like to know how to modify the above code for the latest version.

Comment: I'm not sure why the author used Plugins for such feature. The plugin architecture was removed for simplicity. We're currently considering this approach instead: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/5469

Comment: Thanks @mrdoob.  I'm unfamiliar  with addPostPlugin and custom GL calls.  Could you recommend the most appropriate method for threejs to listen to a file change and update the texture accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

It's removed in r69. If you need it use r68 instead.

Comment: Right, but if it was removed, I'm assumming it was for a reason (change in syntax, new functionality, etc.)  I don't plan on developing this for legacy formats.